# how to resolve this error " [ErrorException] count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"?

Tags: php, laravel-5, error-handling, seed

I'm using windows 10 on my machine. I installed composer and then laravel in the document root i.e. /var/www

I also gave -R 777 permission to folder laravel present in directory /var/www

Then I go to directory laravel using cd /var/www/laravel and run the following command php artisan and I got to see all the available commands there.

Then I typed in php artisan db:seed and got the error

[image]

Comment: How much seeding file you have?

Comment: And you also can call toArray() function on your query.

Comment: Hey Shabeer, 
Is this fixed?

Comment: no its not fixed yet

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the seed code.

Comment: Can you please show me yours seeding file?

Comment: this is my seedercommend

Comment: what version is your ``PHP`` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found this error too when i installed `laravel` with `PHP 7.2`, apparently it [doesn't support 7.2](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/20248) yet, try downgrade your `PHP` to `PHP 7.0`, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You either downgrade to PHP7.1 or use at least Laravel v5.6.